# How to get repeater data using checkbox in WIX?

Tags: javascript, database, checkbox, repeater, velo

I'm showing repeater data from database.Data is showing perfectly in repeater .

Now I want to select Checkbox on one or more repeater but not working.

[image]

When I'm checked checkbox it should show "Air Jordan".But it is showing "Hydra".Also index value are not showing.

[image]

This is my code

```
   export function checkbox1_change(event) {
 // Add your code for this event here: 

   let myid=$w('#text32').text;
  console.log(myid);
  $w("#repeater2").onItemReady( ($item, itemData, index) => {   

 if ($w("#checkbox1").checked) {
   console.log("index:"+index);
   } else {
   console.log("no Index");
   }   

   } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope the clicked item like this

```
export function checkbox1_change(event) {
   let $item = $w.at(event.context);
   let myid = $item('#text32').text;
   console.log(myid);
   /*Checkbox*/
   if($item("#checkbox1").checked){
      console.log("index:"+index);
   }else{
      console.log("no Index");
   }
}
```

Read more about scoping items here: https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/tips-tutorials-examples/removal-of-the-w-parameter-from-event-handlers