# Wix Database searching upload

Tags: database, dataset, velo

I am building a fitness website on Wix. What I have is a database collection of all the training videos. When someone purchases a plan the trainer needs to have their own "Trainer Portal" where they can build the plan for the customer. I need the trainer to be able to filter through the database collection videos and then click "ADD". When they click "ADD" it pushes that video to a data collection then on the same page populate a repeater. The filtering videos I have done with no problem, the problem I am facing is pushing the videos from one database to another database within the webpage.  I can only push the information about the video to another data collection but not the actual video.

If anyone knows if this is possible then please point me in the right direction.

Here is my code below.

```
    // For full API documentation, including code examples, visit https://wix.to/94BuAAs
import wixData from "wix-data";


let debounceTimer;


export function iTitle_keyPress(event, $w) {
    if (debounceTimer) {
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer)
        debounceTimer = undefined;
    }

    debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        filterTitle($w('#iTitle').value);

    }, 200)

    // Add your code for this event here: 
}

function filterTitle(title) {
    console.log($w('#iTitle').value);
    $w('#allVideosDatatSet').setFilter(wixData.filter().contains('title', title))

}


export function addVideos(event) {
    
let toInsert = {
    "video1": $w("#videoPlayer1")
}
    
wixData.insert("Week1", toInsert)
$w("#week1Dataset").save()
    .then( (results) => {

     let item = results;
console.log("Your video was saved!!!!");

})

.catch( (error) => {
    let logErrorMessage = error;
    // console.log(error);
   
} );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

3 things

**First:** I'm assuming you have a button with the `id` of `addVideos` hence the `export function`

Your function `export function addVideos(event) {}` may not be correct, it should be added via the [Properties Panel](https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-working-with-the-properties-panel) and should read something like `export function addVideos_click(event) {}` or add it under the page's `onReady` function like this:

```
$w("#addVideos").onClick( (event) => {
    //put code here
});
```

**Second:** You should scope an item if your button is inside a repeater. Read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404066/11136034) to understand more about scoping an item from a repeater.

**Third:** If the button is inside the repeater then your code should look like below:

```
export function addVideos(event) {
   let $item = $w.at(event.context);
   let toInsert = {
      "video1": $item("#videoPlayer1").src //Missing the .src to get the video source link & also assuming video player is inside the repeater
   };
   wixData.insert("Week1", toInsert) //"Week1" should be the database id
   .then( (results) => {
       console.log("Your video was saved!!!!");
   })
   .catch( (error) => {
       console.log(error);
   });  
}
```

**Regarding this:** *"I can only push the information about the video to another data collection but not the actual video"*

Videos are stored in the Wix Media Manager, the wix database only stores the link to the video which may begin like `wix://video` so you cannot "move a video" between databases, just the link which you can get via `.src` if you want the link of a video player.